# Let $\int_{1}^{3}f(3x-1)dx=20$. Calculate $I=\int_{2}^{5}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

### Let $\int_{1}^{3}f(3x-1)dx=20$. Calculate $I=\int_{2}^{5}f(x)dx$.

My attempts:
Let $t=3x-1 \Rightarrow dt=3dx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{dt}{3}.$
$x=1 \Rightarrow t=2,$
$x=3 \Rightarrow t=8.$
Then $\int_{1}^{3}f(3x-1)dx=20$ can be written $\frac{1}{3}\int_{2}^{8}f(t)dt=20 \Rightarrow \int_{2}^{8}f(t)dt=60 \Rightarrow \int_{2}^{8}f(x)dx=60$.
I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: $$\int_{1}^{3} f(3x-1)\, dx =20 \tag 1$$

Substututing $t=3x-1$, we have $dt = 3\, dx$. Then, $(1)$ becomes $$\int_{2}^{8} \frac13 f(t) \, dt = 20$$ $$\implies \int_{2}^{8} f(x) \, dx =60$$ since the integration is independent of the variable used.

But, I feel that if you have a $5$ as the upper limit of the second integral form, you need to have the upper limit to be $2$ in the first. Because, then $t = 3(2)-1 = 5$.

Comment: May be, one more typo in a book.

Comment: Hmm... I agree.